# How can I search and return only nested documents in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have the following `author` documents, each with `book` documents:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Foo McBarrington",
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Foo Book",
        "published": "2019-05-02"
      },
      {
        "title": "Bar Book",
        "published": "2021-06-13"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Bar McFooington",
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Baz Book",
        "published": "2020-06-23"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to search for and return `books`, ignoring anything from the author documents, and sort the books by `published` field on each book. I should be able to get the books sorted relative to each other:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Foo Book",
    "published": "2019-05-02"
  },
  {
    "title": "Baz Book",
    "published": "2020-06-23"
  },
  {
    "title": "Bar Book",
    "published": "2021-06-13"
  }
]
```

Notice that the book from the second author is sorted in the middle of the two books from the first author.

Is this possible with ElasticSearch? So far I've tried using the `top_hits` aggregation in a nested aggregation but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use a combination of [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html), [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), and [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to achieve your result

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "books"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "books": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "books.title.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_books": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "books.published": {
                      "order": "asc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "books.title",
                    "books.published"
                  ]
                },
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The search result will be

```
"aggregations": {
    "resellers": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "books": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Bar Book",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "latest_books": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": null,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "68477157",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "books",
                      "offset": 1
                    },
                    "_score": null,
                    "_source": {
                      "published": "2021-06-13",       // note this
                      "title": "Bar Book"
                    },
                    "sort": [
                      1623542400000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Baz Book",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "latest_books": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": null,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "68477157",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "2",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "books",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": null,
                    "_source": {
                      "published": "2020-06-23",             // note this
                      "title": "Baz Book"
                    },
                    "sort": [
                      1592870400000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Foo Book",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "latest_books": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": null,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "68477157",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "books",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": null,
                    "_source": {
                      "published": "2019-05-02",     // note this
                      "title": "Foo Book"
                    },
                    "sort": [
                      1556755200000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @knpwrs please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: It works if I remove `.keyword` from `terms.field`, and setting `size` on the terms aggregation appears to let me specify how many books I want. Is there a way to paginate the results?

Comment: @knpwrs for pagination you can either use scroll API or `search_after` parameter. Refer to this part of the documentation to get a detailed understanding -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#paginate-search-results

Comment: @knpwrs please dont forget to upvote and accept the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue :-)

Comment: I found a way to paginate aggregations using a composite aggregation. I'll post another answer, but keep yours accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the books in a paginated format using a [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html):

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "authors": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "books"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "books_composite": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 25,
            "sources": [
              {
                "published": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "books.published",
                    "order": "desc"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get the following page, specify `after`:

````json
I found a way to get the books in a paginated format using a [composite aggregation][1]:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "authors": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "books"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "books_composite": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 25,
            "after": {
              "published": "<DATE HERE>",
              "order": "desc"
            },
            "sources": [
              {
                "published": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "books.published",
                    "order": "desc"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
````